# Exporting mysql data to telegram as contacts

Tags: php, mysql, telegram, contacts

I am trying to export the data from mysql to telegram as contacts, need to code it in PHP. Documentation says, contacts.importContacts can do it. But no idea from where to start. I already have api_id and api_hash.
I am even not able to connect to the api, I don't know how to connect. Somewhere found python code. I tried to write that in php, but no use.

```
<?php
$client = new TelegramClient(api_id, api_hash);
$client->connect();

print_r($client);
```

Comment: Provide a code sample

Comment: I am even not able to connect to the api, I don't know how to connect. Somewhere found python code. I tried to write that in php, but no use.